# Get URL of a http get request in flutter app

Tags: http, url, dart, get, flutter

I am trying to get the URL of the following get request;

```
String url = ['url_here'];
Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
final response = await http.get(url);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} else {
throw Exception('Failed to load post');
}
}
```

I get a statuscode of 200.

Any ideas?

To clarify, When you enter the url in a browser it brings me to a page with a url that has a code in it. I am trying to extract that code.

Comment: can you add some of your logs

Comment: what would you like to see?

Comment: Are you using HTTP from `dart:io` or from `package:http`?

Comment: import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Answer (score 5):

`followRedirects` is `true` by default and I haven't found a way to get the URL it redirects to this way.

Setting `followRedirects = false` returns the new address in the `location` header.

```
  final url = 'http://wikipedia.net';
  final client = http.Client();
  final request = new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url))
    ..followRedirects = false;
  final response = await client.send(request);

  print(response.headers['location']);
  print(response.statusCode);
```

If you want to fetch the content of the redirect address, you can send a new request with the URL from `location` or just with the default (`followRedirects = true`)

Comment: is redirect is false

Comment: What is the response code? Is the `location` header set?

Comment: Is it a public URL that I can test myself with?

Comment: response.statusCode = 200, and no the location header is not set

Comment: its not public. i'm trying to connect fitbit to my app. on their OAuth 2.0 tutorial page they build the url with clientsecret etc. 

they say:

Copy and paste the code that you can find in the redirect URL after the user has clicked the "allow" button. Example: http://localhost:8888/callback?code=7b64c4b088b9c841d15bcac15d4aa7433d35af3e#_=_, the code you need to paste from that example is 7b64c4b088b9c841d15bcac15d4aa7433d35af3e. Don't include the “#_=_”.

Comment: I updated my answer. The URL redirects from `wikipedia.net` to `wikipedia.org`